# How to declare a FK, uniqueidentifier in a SQL cursor

Tags: sql-server-2008, cursor, uniqueidentifier, declare

I am unsure how to declare a uniqueidentifier in a sql cursor. Right now I have it defined as nvarchar (50) for @activity_id but I am afraid that is not correct.

```
declare @activity_id nvarchar (50)
declare @fullname nvarchar(200)


declare cur cursor for
select c.activityid, d.fullname from ActivityPointerBase as a
join PhoneCallBase as b on b.ActivityId = a.ActivityId
join ActivityPartyBase as c on c.ActivityId = a.ActivityId
join SystemUserBase as d on d.SystemUserId = c.PartyId
where b.new_Source = '100000000' and c.ParticipationTypeMask = '1'
order by d.FullName ASC
```

Comment: never-mind. I ran it and it worked, I was afraid the uniqueidentifier would have to converted first, i guess not. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

never-mind. I ran it and it worked, I was afraid the uniqueidentifier would have to converted first, i guess not. thanks!